# Duda en Python- Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy aprendiendo `Python` y estoy trabajando este código:
La idea es crear una pantalla, luego que el usuario introduzca una contraseña, y si esta es correcta **(==123)** que aparezca una pantalla que diga **"Bienvenido al sistema"**, y si no lo es, una que diga **"error..."**, el tema es que cuando pongo la contraseña que sería la correcta **(123)** en el campo me tira la pantalla que dice **"error.."** en lugar de la de **"Bienvenido al sistema"**, no sé en qué le estoy errando. Desde ya, muchas gracias.

```py
    from tkinter import *
    from tkinter import ttk



    def p():
        if clave==123:
            r=Tk()
            r.geometry("380x300")
            r.config(bg="pink")
            c=Label(r,text="Bienvenido al sistema")
            c.grid(column=1,row=2)
        else:
            h=Tk()
            h.geometry("380x300")
            h.config(bg="pink")
            u=Label(h,text="error en la clave")
            u.grid(column=1,row=2)






    g=Tk()
    g.geometry("360x360")
    g.config(bg="black")
    s=Frame(g,width="180",height="180")
    s.config(bg="red")
    s.grid(column=4, row=4,padx=(5,5),pady=(10,10))
    etiqueta=Label(s,text="ingrese su contraseña")
    etiqueta.config(bg="blue",fg="black")
    etiqueta.grid(column=1,row=2)
    ingreso=Entry(s,width=15)
    ingreso.grid(column=2,row=2)
    b=Button(s,text="salir",bg="green",fg="black",command=s.destroy)
    b.grid(column=2,row=4)
    d=Button(s,text="ok",bg="green",fg="black",command=p)
    d.grid(column=3,row=4)

    clave=ingreso.get()






    g.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero `.get()` devuelve un string asi que seria : `if clave=="123":`

Y Segundo el get lo ejecutas antes de inicial el programa con el mainloop por lo que siempre esta vacio lo puedes actualizar cada vez que le des al boton y listo :

```
def p():

    clave=ingreso.get()

    if clave=="123":
        r=Tk()
        r.geometry("380x300")
        r.config(bg="pink")
        c=Label(r,text="Bienvenido al sistema")
        c.grid(column=1,row=2)
    else:
        h=Tk()
        h.geometry("380x300")
        h.config(bg="pink")
        u=Label(h,text="error en la clave")
        u.grid(column=1,row=2)
```